# Fading image captions on hover in css

Tags: css, hover, transition, caption

I'm working on my portfolio and I did some fancy things to my image thumbnails. I now want my hover caption to fade in/out on hover.

This is my code so far;
HTML:

```
<a href="1.jpg" class="mask"><img src="1.jpg" />
        <span class="caption fade-caption">  
        <h3>Fade Caption</h3>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>  
        </span>  
    </a>
```

CSS:

```
    .mask {
    position:relative;
    height:180px;
    width:240px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px #000;
    border:5px solid #f6f6f6;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
}
.mask img {
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(15deg);
    transform:rotate(15deg);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-150px; /* half the height */
    margin-left:-200px; /*half the width */
}

.mask:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
}

.mask .caption {  
    background-color: rgba(222,169,188,0.9);  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    left: 0;  
}  

.mask .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 220px;  
    height: 180px;  
    text-align: left;  
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 15px; 
    display:none; 
    font-size:0.8em;
}  

.mask:hover .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
    display:inline;
      width: 220px;  
        height: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;   
    }
```

I thought I needed to add a fade-caption class and put the transitions on the :hover state, but apparently that's not right. I'm not so skilled with transitions yet and I'm hoping someone can help me with this since I couldn't find a tutorial that could help me with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/drsrd/) for a working example. Full CSS below:

```
.mask {
    position:relative;
    height:180px;
    width:240px;
    box-shadow:0 0 1px #000;
    border:5px solid #f6f6f6;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
}
.mask img {
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-150px; /* half the height */
    margin-left:-200px; /*half the width */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(15deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(15deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(15deg);
    transform:rotate(15deg);
}

.caption {  
    background-color: rgba(222,169,188,0.9);  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 15px; 
    font-size:0.8em;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;   
}  

.mask:hover .caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
}
```

Importantly, the `transition` styling is on the element itself, not just its `:hover` state. That way it will both fade in and out. If those style are just on `:hover`, the element will fade in but disappear immediately rather than fading out.

You can't transition between `display: none` and `display: block/whatever`. So, you need to let the `opacity` in this instance be what visually hides your caption. You could add the proprietary ms-filters to get old-IE support.

Other points to note:

1. I consolidated your `.caption` and `.fade-caption` classes for the sake of simplicity.
2. There's no need to re-declare things that are already set for the `:hover` state, you just need to state those things that need to change.
3. There's no need for prefixes on `box-shadow` any more, just use the final version.
4. You were getting a bit confused with positioning your caption, making it `absolute` but also setting a `width` and `height`. For simplicity's sake I have just set all four valules to `0`.
5. You don't need to declare the `z-index` here, just let the browser's normal stacking order sort it for you. If you need to place the caption before the image in the markup though, you would need to add this back in.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your transitions aren't current doing what you might expect is that the `display` properties (going from `none` to `inline`) on the caption is preventing the `opacity` from transitioning, and your transitions should also be applied to the element before you make any changes (i.e. before hover - in the regular state). Relying purely on the `opacity` to fade the caption in and out should work a treat:

```
.mask .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 220px;  
    height: 180px;  
    text-align: left;  
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 15px; 
    font-size:0.8em;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}  

.mask:hover .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
    width: 220px;  
    height: 180px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9NFV/

EDIT: Ninja'd, but I'll keep this answer here anyway for now.